# Не отображаются данные в ячейках при Parse ,сделал в унаследованные классов

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse.com

Подскажите правильно ли я сделал унаследование классов ?Не могу понять почему в TableView не отображаются данные.Внес данные на сервере.Делал break в таблице пишется что передача идет и одно данное передано .

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class SportViewController: BaseViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()

       self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "uklogo.png"))

    let queryMatch = PFQuery(className: "betting")
    queryMatch.addAscendingOrder("match")
    queryMatch.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?) in
        if error == nil {
            print (objects!.count)
        }
         else {
        }
    })


}

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            }


    class SportViewController: PFQueryTableViewController{


       func tableView (_tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object : PFObject?)-> PFTableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prognozCell", for: indexPath) as! EventCell
            cell.dataLabel.text = object?.object(forKey: "data") as? String
            cell.matchLabel.text = object?.object(forKey: "match") as? String
            cell.progLabel.text = object?.object(forKey: "prognoz") as? String
            cell.noteText.text = object?.object(forKey: "note") as? String

            let imageFile = object?.object(forKey: "image") as? PFFile

            cell.imagesP.image = UIImage(named: "sport1")
            cell.imagesP.file = imageFile
            cell.imagesP.loadInBackground()



               self.loadObjects()
            return cell


        }
        func tableView (_tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> CGFloat {
            if indexPath.row + 1 > (self.objects?.count)! {
                return 10
            }
        let height = super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
            return height
        }

    }



}
```